# Боковая обводка у input-а HTML

Tags: html, input

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такую обводку у input-а?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Пример

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-input{
    margin: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
.b-input:before,
.b-input:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;  right: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #f00;
}
.b-input:before{
    top: 0;
}
.b-input:after{
    bottom: 0;
}
input{
    border: none;
    display: block;
    max-width: 250px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding: 5px 45px 5px 30px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 4px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="b-input">
        <input type="email" placeholder="email">
    </div>
</form>
```